# Identifying a transistor, responsible of driving a 12 V fan

Tags: transistors, identification, surface-mount

I have blown this transistor while probing a GPU card, I usually take as much care as I could to probe a living device, but yeah, it's not the first time.

I have identified the short I caused and it was a shorted transistor (which also shorted or opened another transistor that connects to the base of this transistor from its collector). It is apparently an NPN one based on the research of the marking code, but based on the need of that transistor it seems more of PNP transistor. I searched many places with the marking **ADBA** and number **2A** on the side as shown in the picture, but could not find any definite answer, as **AD** is the marking and **BA** is something like year/week or something else. Honestly, I'm no expert.

How do I identify something similar? I already did the SMD code search with the type SOT-23 or SC-70 etc., but with no success. Or maybe I already found what I want but there are many and they all seem to be doing different things, but can still fit the need above to drive a 12 V fan.

[image]

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but if someone agrees, it seems to be an equivalent to N-channel mosfet! 2N7002P https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/2N7002P.pdf

Comment: its a p-channel mosfet AO3413
http://www.aosmd.com/pdfs/marking/AO3413.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The 2A part would represent a 3906, a BJT PNP. Not sure what the ADBA would be. The 3906 would fit your preliminary analysis.

Comment: Thanks Louis, is the 2A the marking in this case?

Comment: That is my thinking, Not sure that the ADBA stand for. The 2A marking is standardize for 3906, so if it's not a 3906, why would they indicated 2A. I'm pretty confident.

Comment: Thanks again, Louis. based on the analysis, it seems to be correct, I will accept your answer, I will also use a PNP BJT with some what higher current rates, as I have seen this transistor explode in several web posts

Comment: A 4403 would be a good substitute as most parameters are very similar, but can drive 600mA as compare to 200mA for the 3906. Thanks for the vote .

Comment: Thanks again, Louis, I went with a 2F alternative KST2907A

Comment: Louis, thanks once again, I think this is not the correct answer anymore. so far I have found the exact same chip with name ADEA instead of ADBA, and it has a side marking of number 11 so its not a 2A chip its more of an AD sot-23 chip, I have got the same GPU as defect and found that out.

Comment: This can still be the correct answer, but I need to confirm this, as if the 11 marking is equal to the 2A then its possible, but based on the naming difference it seems to be sticking with the AD marking i still cant tell what it actually is anyway :)

Comment: The 11 marking (PDTA114TT or PDTA114TE) is for a PNP very similar to the 3906 with the exception of an added base resistor. This may be either a replacement for availability, or a design fix. My money would be on the design fix.  The TT and TE are not the same size and footprint. Validate with your component dimension.

Comment: Thanks Louis, the PDTA114TT fits more in size, I'm still actually researching a bit more, on that 11 datasheet it reads 100mA collector current, which sounds a bit low for driving two 80mm fans, the 3906 can drive up to 200mA which seems suitable for driving them, could it be that these are actually voltage detectors, specifically for the hall sensor of these fans, as I noticed when i actually planted a general purpose PNP BJTS there, and ran the Graphic card, i get three fans running, and I could change their speed, but there were no rpm recorded.

Comment: This one for example https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX6375-MAX6380.pdf at page number 5 it says ADB and ADE, which also fits the two chips marking i mentioned

Comment: You most likely will need to create the interconnections diagram between that device and to device it connects to. It should help identify it.

Comment: Thanks Louis, I think I finally found what it is, AO3413 this is the ADBA mosfet chip.

Comment: @User9123, Yes looks like it, and the sideways 2A is the assembly lot code.